# Separate Ansible Vaults For Different Environments?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible to handle endpoint differences for different environments.
This is done through the use of variables and the ansible-xml extension.

For example, I have a task called "endpoints.yml" setup within a role called "myapp". This task sets a variety of configuration parameters within configuration files, substituting in variables.

**/roles/myapp/tasks/endpoints.yml**

```
 —> set value in app config file to: {{ db_user }}
 —> set value in app config file to: {{ db_password }}
```

Since my non-prod environments share a single endpoint, the values for these variables are setup in the role's default file:

**/roles/myapp/defaults/main.yml**

```
 —> db_user: myuser_ro
 —> db_passwordd: some_password
```

For the prod environment, I am overwriting the default with a group_variable (since this takes precedence):

**/environments/prod/group_vars/myapp_servers**

```
 —> db_user: produser_ro
 —> db_password: some_other_password
```

This all works great and allows for us to use a single playbook/role for all environments. However, I am wanting to move take advantage of ansible-vault to move the password values out of these files and into an encrypted file.

However, there will still be different values for prod and non-prod.
I could create a new "vars" file in the role called "pass.yml", encrypt it with ansible-vault, and then reference it from the task with an "include_vars: pass.yml".

But this doesn't explain how I account for needing different (encrypted) variables for different environments.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose the best solution might be to have multiple vaults and reference them with --vault-password-file when calling ansible playbook:  (ie: myapp_prod_vault.yml, myapp_nonprod_vault.yml)

Comment: Wait, why can't you use group_vars and have separate vault files for each group? Your question is rather confusing, hard to understand what exactly you are trying to explain.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are using a multi-environment structure like [this](http://www.geedew.com/setting-up-ansible-for-multiple-environment-deployments/).  In this case you can create a vault file for each environment.

```
environments
├── dev
│   └── group_vars
│       └── all
│           └── secrets
└── prod
    └── group_vars
        └── all
            └── secrets
```

Each "secrets" file can have its own password.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple vault passwords in a single ansible configuration are not currently supported by ansible vault. You must use the same vault password to encrypt both the prod and non-prod environment files.

Comment: Thanks to whomever upvoted my -1 that wasn't deserved :)

Answer (score 2):

Time has passed since the previous answers, Ansible 2.2 limits you to use one vault password for the whole playbook execution but it does not impede you to have different files encrypted with different vault passwords as long as they are not used at the same.

In few words, you may have a testing environment with a vault password different from production.

I did a PoC, you can check it here:

https://github.com/brianmori/ansible-poc